# Как изменить раздел с которого загружается GRUB

Tags: bash, debian, shell, grub, hdd

Мой debian8 изначально находился на диске sda8 все работало

[image: scr]

после нескольких махинаций с размером разделов из под windows7, debian8 перебрался на диск (hd0,2) и grub загружается только после консольных команд

```
set root=(hd0,2)
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Подскажите как настроить загрузчик что бы при каждой загрузке не вводить эти команды?

Comment: Повторная его установка точно решит проблему.

Comment: Если есть возможность загрузиться или хотя бы за'chroot'иться в систему, то просто обнови конфиг... как — написано в шапке `/etc/default/grub`. Можно и вручную поправить `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. ЗЫ: это же второй груб, ведь так?

Comment: @D-side При переустановке вываливаются ошибки

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, загрузится в систему получается, но команда `sudo update-grub` не помогла

Comment: и к ошибке заодно можно вывод `update-grub` и `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`